# Only show slot if it has content, when slot has no name?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077358/8455110), we can check if a slot has content or not. But I am using a slot which has no name:

```js
<template>
    <div id="map" v-if="!isValueNull">
        <div id="map-key">{{ name }}</div>
        <div id="map-value">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            name: {type: String, default: null}
        },
        computed: {
            isValueNull() {
                console.log(this.$slots)
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am using like this:

```html
<my-map name="someName">{{someValue}}</my-map>
```

How can I not show the component when it has no value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All slots have a name. If you don't give it a name explicitly then it'll be called `default`.

So you can check for `$slots.default`.

A word of caution though. `$slots` is not reactive, so when it changes it won't invalidate any computed properties that use it. However, it will trigger a re-rendering of the component, so if you use it directly in the template or via a method it should work fine.

Here's an example to illustrate that the caching of computed properties is not invalidated when the slot's contents change.

```js
const child = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>computedHasSlotContent: {{ computedHasSlotContent }}</div>
      <div>methodHasSlotContent: {{ methodHasSlotContent() }}</div>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `,
  
  computed: {
    computedHasSlotContent () {
      return !!this.$slots.default
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    methodHasSlotContent () {
      return !!this.$slots.default
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  components: {
    child
  },
  
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
  <child>
    <p v-if="show">Child text</p>
  </child>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you dont pass that value as prop to map component.

```
<my-map :someValue="someValue" name="someName">{{someValue}}</my-map>
```

and in my-map add prop:

```
   props: {
            someValue:{default: null},
        },
```

So now you just check if someValue is null:

```
 <div id="map" v-if="!someValue">
    ...
</div
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I just want to know how to access a slot with no name.